# How to save variables with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, gson, state

I have my own Objects which I need to store for later use. The User saves this object, it is turned into a JSON String, then when the User is connected to a network, the JSON String is turned back into the object operations are performed on it.

My problem is that, at run time, how do I know how to store the object?

i.e

```
Gson gson= new Gson();
String pointOfInterest = gson.toJson(point);
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedprefEditor = application_shared_preferences.edit();
sharedprefEditor.putString(?KEY?,pointOfInterest);
```

What can I use for the value of KEY? If I use an index, it will get reset every time I open or close the app, and this will replace my Objects.

**Edit**
Sorry I didn't make this clear enough, the method that the above code is in can be run an arbitrary number of times and there could be several pointsOfInterest to store.

Comment: You might have missed something about SharedPreferences. The `key` uniquely identifies the value you are saving, and you can get it back with that same key. Nothing will be "reset" unless you explicitly do so. Don't forget to `commit()` your changes, though

Comment: Don't use SharedPreferences.  It's not designed to store data like this.  As the name suggests, it's to store user settings (although it has other uses too).  Simple booleans, Strings that kind of thing.  Just write your JSON to a file in private storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you use an index, the Preference will stay forever:

For instance:

```
sharedprefEditor.putString("JSON569",pointOfInterest);
```

You can also save the index in an other preference; for instance separated by a column:

```
sharedprefEditor.putString("indexes","569;789;852");
```

You can, easily check if an instance exists:

```
myPreference.getString("JSON789","").contentEquals("");
```

Or get all your instances:

```
for (int anIndex:indexes)
    Log.i("TAG","Current value: "+myPreference.getString("JSON"+anIndex,""));
```

Please xplain a little bit more your question, I see no difficulties there/

Comment: Sorry man I forgot to note that the code could be run several times and I may need to store a number of PointOfInterest objects

Comment: The problem there is that if I use an Index and then the app is minimized the index is reset, so when it boots up again it will start overwriting the old ones

Comment: Save the index in an other preference_

Answer (score 0):

You can name the key whatever you want, just make it consistent.  One way to do it is make a constant in your class for it:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final String OBJECT_KEY = "myObjectKey";

    ...
```

Then when you save your object:

```
Gson gson= new Gson();
String pointOfInterest = gson.toJson(point);
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedprefEditor = application_shared_preferences.edit();
sharedprefEditor.putString(OBJECT_KEY,pointOfInterest);
```

When you load it, just use `OBJECT_KEY` to get a string out of the shared preferences:

```
String objectString = sharedPrefs.getString( OBJECT_KEY, "" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I forgot to mention that the above code could be run a number of times and there could well be more than one object

Comment: You're better off making your own [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) database then.